# IWindowsFormsEditorService delay after closing

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid, uitypeeditor

I need to have a custom property value editor integrated into `PropertyGrid` control. Code is listed below

```
internal class VariableTypeEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        IWindowsFormsEditorService service = provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)) as IWindowsFormsEditorService;

        Type type = context.GetType();
        PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty("OwnerGrid");

        IPlugIn plug = context.Instance as IPlugIn;

        if (service != null && property != null
                            && plug != null)
        {
            PropertyGrid owner = property.GetValue(context) as PropertyGrid;

            if (owner != null)
            {
                Collection<VariableWrapper> variables = owner.Tag as Collection<VariableWrapper>;

                if (variables != null)
                {
                    VariableEditorForm editor = new VariableEditorForm();
                    editor.Value = plug.VariableName;
                    editor.Variables = variables.Select(o => o.Variable).Where(o => o.ValueType == plug.VariableType).ToArray();
                    editor.TopLevel = false;
                    editor.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler((sender, args) =>
                    {
                        service.CloseDropDown();
                    });

                    service.DropDownControl(editor);
                    value = editor.Value;
                }
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

I want it to work this way:

- to change value of the property user opens up the DropDown with `VariableEditorForm` (using PropertyGrid)
- user selects one of the values listed in the `VariableEditorForm` and after that `VariableEditorForm` would close automatically

It works now. But for some reason it takes 2-3 seconds before EditValue method would return its value.

Why `service.DropDownControl(editor)` does not return immediately after its closing?

Comment: This is unexpected. Have you try to call CloseDropDown it on another even (before FormClosed)? Have you try to debug? Are you sure there's no exception happening (the property grid can silently swallow a lot of errors).

Comment: @SimonMourier - I did several experiments and noticed that IWindowsFormsEditorService waits for the MainThread to be free (from rendering main window for example).

Comment: Difficult to dig further w/o a full reproducing code.

Comment: The only thing I see is that you are not disposing the form, but I doubt that that is the issue.

Comment: @TnTinMn Please take a look at my answer. Do you have any thoughts about how to improve it? Thank you.

Comment: @SimonMourier What do you think about the solution that I came up with? Is it a bad idea to keep it this way?

Comment: Like I say, the problem seems specific to your code/context (you talk about a timer), so w/o any reproducing code, it's dificult to say if there's a better way. If it works for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. I don't like but it works. Code is listed below.

```
            public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
            {
                IWindowsFormsEditorService service = provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)) as IWindowsFormsEditorService;

                Type type = context.GetType();
                PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty("OwnerGrid");

                IPlugIn plug = context.Instance as IPlugIn;

                if (service != null && property != null
                                    && plug != null)
                {
                    PropertyGrid owner = property.GetValue(context) as PropertyGrid;

                    if (owner != null)
                    {
                        Collection<VariableWrapper> variables = owner.Tag as Collection<VariableWrapper>;

                        if (variables != null)
                        {
                            VariableEditorForm editor = new VariableEditorForm();
                            editor.Value = plug.VariableName;
                            editor.Variables = variables.Select(o => o.Variable).Where(o => o.ValueType == plug.VariableType).ToArray();
                            editor.TopLevel = false;
                            editor.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler((sender, args) =>
                            {
                                // disable main form rendering
                                User32.PostMessage(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, Messages.WM_DISABLE_RENDER, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                                service.CloseDropDown();
                            });

                            service.DropDownControl(editor);

                            // enable main form rendering
                            User32.PostMessage(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, Messages.WM_ENABLE_RENDER, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                            value = editor.Value;
                            editor.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }

                return value;
            }
```

Thing is that I have a panel on my main form that uses timer to constantly render itself. I noticed that my problem goes away each time I disable that timer. So not having any better solition I decided to post message to my main form to enable/disable mentioned timer.

I would appreciate if someone would provide a proper solution to my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible to have value of const : `WM_DISABLE_RENDER` and `WM_ENABLE_RENDER`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).